# access "in memory" database from other thread

Tags: sqlite

I have created an in memory database using the statement:

```
rc = sqlite3_open(":memory:", &db);
```

I need to access this database in other thread (for reading data).
Is there any way to access this in memory database in other thread?

The documentation says:

> Every `:memory:` database is distinct from every other. So, opening two
>   database connections each with the filename `:memory:` will create two
>   independent in-memory databases.

If I create multiple in memory database, how can I access these databases from other thread?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `db` variable in your code becomes the pointer to the SQLite db object created:

```
int sqlite3_open(
  const char *filename,   /* Database filename (UTF-8) */
  sqlite3 **ppDb          /* OUT: SQLite db handle */
);
```

Ref.: http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_open

This is the pointer you will use in your different threads to execute statements. For example, you prepare statements with the following function to which you'll pass your `db` pointer:

```
int sqlite3_prepare(
  sqlite3 *db,            /* Database handle */
  const char *zSql,       /* SQL statement, UTF-8 encoded */
  int nByte,              /* Maximum length of zSql in bytes. */
  sqlite3_stmt **ppStmt,  /* OUT: Statement handle */
  const char **pzTail     /* OUT: Pointer to unused portion of zSql */
);
```

Ref.: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/prepare.html

**EDIT:**

I don't know if you can change the name of the memory database that you open with `sqlite3_open(":memory:", ...)`, but it does have a name. Also you can attach additional in-memory databases.

There is a good chance that the initially opened in-memory database name is `main`. You can verify that by running the statement `pragma database_list`.

You can attach more in-memory database by running statements such as `ATTACH DATABASE ':memory:' AS db2;`.

Here is a quick demo of the above using the sqlite3 client:

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ sqlite3
SQLite version 3.7.7.1 2011-06-28 17:39:05
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .headers on
sqlite> pragma database_list;
seq|name|file
0|main|
sqlite> attach database ':memory:' AS db2;
sqlite> pragma database_list;
seq|name|file
0|main|
2|db2|
sqlite> create table main.foo (bar int);
sqlite> create table db2.foo (bar int);
sqlite> insert into main.foo values (5);
sqlite> insert into db2.foo select * from main.foo;
sqlite> select * from db2.foo;
bar
5
```

Comment: Can we name a memory database? I am creating a web application and I am sending request to get data from the database. How can we access these databases?